# jqplot graph text color

Tags: html, css, jqplot

I am working with jqplot and I am trying to achieve couple of things

1. I am trying to change the text color that appears along side x and y axis.
2. I am trying to remove the graph border (Top border and Right border only)

This is what my graph looks like

[image]

On xaxis you will notice the numbers 30 - 90 I need that to be in white and on y axis you will notice dates, i need that to be in white as well

This is what my JS looks like

```
var line2 = [
    ['1/1/2008', 42],
    ['2/14/2008', 56],
    ['3/7/2008', 39],
    ['4/22/2008', 81]
];

var plot2 = $.jqplot('progress_chart', [line2], {
    seriesColors: [ "#F2A809"],

    series:[
        {
            // Change our line width and use a diamond shaped marker.
            lineWidth:5,
            markerOptions: { style:'circle' }
        }
    ],
    grid:{
        background: 'transparent',      // CSS color spec for background color of grid.
        borderColor: '#ffffff',     // CSS color spec for border around grid.
        borderWidth: 2.0           // pixel width of border around grid.
    },

    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            shadowAlpha : '0.1',
            tickOptions: {
                // labelPosition: 'middle',
                angle: 15,
                showGridline: false,
                color: '#ffffff'
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: '',
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                showGridline: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I will really appreciate any assistance here.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @redditor answer I got it to work, however that was causing everything graph x and y axis text to turn white. This particular graph was inside another div called `tab-inner-content` so I got it to work using the following CSS.

```
.tab-inner-content .jqplot-target {
    color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `color: white`

Comment: where this `color: white` needs to go? if in xaxis or yaxis i have tried it and it does not work

Comment: I think inside tickOptions: {
color: 'white'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqplot uses several CSS rules to create the various graph styles. It looks like the labels are controlled by the `jqplot-target` class, so you need something like:

```
.jqplot-target {
     color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @Baig Make a jsfiddle.net - without seeing the rest of your code we can only guess.....

Comment: if i remove the `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,` and then add your suggestion in CSS then it works, but this messes up other graphs being used by making them all white

Comment: @Baig Like I said, make a http://www.jsfiddle.net - you're probably putting something in the wrong order or perhaps bypassing another CSS rule.

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer as this helped, I will update my question to show how i got it work using this answer

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
tickOptions: {
                // labelPosition: 'middle',
                angle: 15,
                showGridline: false,
                color: '#ffffff'
            }
```

by

```
tickOptions: {
                // labelPosition: 'middle',
                angle: 15,
                showGridline: false,
                textColor: '#ffffff'
            }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the correct option to set the color is 'textColor'